# pythonbrew bashrc awk line no longer works

Tags: python, awk, pythonbrew

I recently upgraded my FreeBSD box and now pythonbrew seems to be broken. It bails out of the .pythonbrew/etc/bashrc file on this line:

```
PATH_WITHOUT_PYTHONBREW=$(printf "$PATH" | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: "/${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}/ {next} {print}" | sed -e 's#:$##')
```

Gives the error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
   context is
      >>> //home/myusername/. <<< pythonbrew/ {next} {print}
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

That PATH_ROOT variable is

```
/home/myusername/.pythonbrew
```

Comment: It seem for me that you try to read variable inside `awk` code.  Use  `awk` like this `awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: -v path=$path_root '$0==path {next...`

Comment: Does `${PATH_ROOT//\//\\\/}` work? Though as @Jotne suggests using `-v` is likely a better plan. Though with `$0 ~ path` if you want the regex match and not equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't put variables in your printf formatting argument as that'll fail when your variable contains printf formatting charcters, e.g. '%'. So use `printf "%s" "$PATH"` instead of `printf "$PATH"`.
2. It is never a good idea to use double quotes to delimit an awk script as it introduces double quoting hell in the rest of the script. So use `'/'"${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}"'/{...}'` instead of `"/${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}/{...}"`
3. It is almost never a good idea to allow shell variable expansion to provide parts of the body of your awk script dynamically as it introduces the potential for bizarre syntax errors. So use `awk -v path_root="${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}" '$0 ~ path_root{...}'` instead of `'/'"${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}"'/{...}'`.
4. Rather than test for a condition and use next and then use a print if the condition isn't present, you can just test for the negation of the condition.
5. When setting 2 variables to the same value (e.g. RS and ORS), it's clearest to set them together rather than separately.

So, all together, as a starting point your script would be:

```
PATH_WITHOUT_PYTHONBREW=$(printf "%s" "$PATH" |
    awk -v path_root="${PATH_ROOT//\//\/}" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=":"} $0 !~ path_root' |
    sed -e 's#:$##')
```

assuming your PATH_ROOT manipulation makes sense.

It could be further improved but that should be enough to get rid of your error.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! There is an extra single quote in there in front of $0 that I can't remove as it wants the edits to be at least 6 characters, but once that is removed it works great. I'll see about adding this as a patch to pythonbrew as well.

Comment: You're welcome and I updated my script to remove that single quote. If you'd like to update your question with some samples of what "PATH" can contain and what you'd want "PATH_WITHOUT_PYTHONBREW" to be set to given those PATH settings, I'm sure we could show you how to do it trivially in a single awk command rather than invoking multiple commands and pipes.